# I need to download the file to the local sandbox, but the download link is a blob link, how can I download it in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I click the button I will get a download url is "blob: http://v9.api.vip.groupnp.cn/html-docx/9d9685bc-6e8c-4a88-99f5-d9fc3edd384d". This should be able to download a word File, but I tried to use AFNetworking to download, but it failed, so how should I use object-c to download such a linked file in the iOS environment？

this is the downloadurl：  blob:http://v9.api.vip.groupnp.cn/html-docx/9d9685bc-6e8c-4a88-99f5-d9fc3edd384d

Comment: http link are disabled by default. Use https or consider configure App Transport Security (ATS)

Comment: I know that http is disabled by default, so I gave permission to load http, but the problem is that the download URL is blob: at the beginning, which prevents me from downloading the file in the usual way.

Comment: you just need to remove the "blob" string and get the actual blob data from http url.

Comment: If I remove the blob string, this link is useless

Answer (score -1):

We found a relevant solution. Our Html5 developers transcoded this blob-containing URL using the js method to base64, so that the iOS side can process the transcoded string and finally write it locally Docx documentation